# other alternatives to onclick event to execute a php function

Tags: php, javascript, html

i have  read that there's no way i could use JavaScript onclick() event to execute a php script, what other alternatives i could use?

what i need is a button to execute a php function that would initiate connection to a remote soap client and a server 'reply status indicator' .

```
<?php 

 ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

 $client = new
 SoapClient("http://xxxx:8085/axis2/services/RegistrationService?wsdl",array('excepltions' => 0));

---- rest of codes omitted ----
    ?>
```

Comment: what do you really want? you can use ajax for that

Answer (score 1):

There is no *direct* way. That is because JS runs in the browser and PHP runs on the server. You have to make a request to the server. You can do that a few ways:

One option: Make a link that sends you to a php page that has your PHP code and then redirects you back.

Or: AJAX. jQuery makes it pretty easy. You can probably use [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

```
$.get("test.php", function(data){
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

test.php would have your PHP code in it and it would simply echo the status returned. When the request completes, the page will alert "Data Loaded: " + whatever the php echoed.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I am missing something but why could you not use a onclick function using ajax to access the soap function.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/